# Do Android controls/widgets have choice of styles?

Tags: android

I have a column of Checkboxes and associated EditTexts and I want one pair of these to have a distinct appearance because it has a distinct significance.

Short of writing custom controls, or using custom drawables, does Android have any way to style or alter the appearance of basic controls like buttons, checkboxes, etc, in the XML where the control is declared?    Or is there just one native style or appearance for all Android Checkboxes, Buttons, EditTexts, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost custom everything related to style:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

In fact, an Android Button is just a TextView with different style. In source code, the Button is just an extend to TextView with no overriding.

Comment: Yes I understand I can create custom styles in a separate XML file but that seems like overkill just to alter the appearance of one control.   That's why I asked "does Android have any way to style or alter the appearance of basic controls like buttons, checkboxes, etc, in the XML where the control is declared?"   E.g, can I give a checkbox a different color of style of check?

Comment: It's not overkill.  It's one additional file in which to put all of your style declarations.  That said, you can also set pretty much all things you set in the style as direct attributes in the XML layout...  but you will  need to write the same stuff for every widget that has the same style.

Comment: I only need to do it for that one checkbox.  But I'm still not sure I understand the answer.   Say I want to change the border thinkness, check color and background color in XAML (in WPF) I can do         <CheckBox Content="#" Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="10" Background="#FFED7D7D" Foreground="#FF00ED00" />  ...what's the equivalent of this in Android XML?

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html in XML Attribute (and inherited attributes) section. Basically, everything you mentioned should be fine, except border might need to define a 9-patch drawable to do so (correct me if I am wrong)